# Regex for 13 digit number, last four digit should only be 0 to 3

Tags: regular-expressions

I have added regex ([0-9])\13   ^0-4, total 13 digit number will allow and last four digit should be between 0 to 3 but this is not working.

([0-9])\13  ^0-4)

for ex: 123456789**0123**
or  789153457**2103**
Like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
[0-9]{9}+[0-3]{4}+
```

First part: `[0-9]{9}+` assures you have 9 digits at start and second part: `[0-3]{4}+` adds 4 digits from 0 to 3.

You can take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]{9}[0-3]{4}
```

You can try this expression. if you want to check it further, get testing from this site: https://regexr.com/